# SSRS: Can you have the label of a (pie) chart be both the category AND the Percent

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report, label, pie-chart

I have a pie chart in SSRS.   It contains many categories so it is kinda hard to read.  What I would like to do is include the category AND the percent in the label, but I am not sure how to do this.

You can include the category by setting the label to `[CategoryName]`  (this is the default).
You can include the percent by changing that to `#PERCENT`.
But I cannot seam to figure out how to include both.

Is there a VBA formula that I can add that will give me both?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can actually just shove `#PERCENT` into a larger string.

Some simple data:

[image]

And a simple chart based on this:

[image]

The expression used for the labels is:

```
=Fields!grp.Value & ": " & "#PERCENT{P2}"
```

Here `{P2}` is controlling the formatting. You should be able to adapt to your scenario.

Alternatively, for greater control you can just add the relevant % calculation in the label expression; in the above case this would be:

```
=Fields!grp.Value
    & ": "
    & Format(Sum(Fields!val.Value) / Sum(Fields!val.Value, "MyDataSet"), "P2")
```

Which in this case gives identical results to the above.

Comment: SSRS automatically will remind you, but this requires UseValueAsLabel be set to false.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207017.aspx), you can use the `#LEGENDTEXT` chart keyword to write the text that corresponds to the text of the legend item into the label.